# Azure Web App - Kudu github deployment not working

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have web app written in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and React, deployed to the free Azure Web App service on Linux (UK South) using the GitHub kudu deployment.

It's been working fine for months, deploying new versions regularly, but yesterday the latest deployment failed a couple of times with an error that read something like "build failed - see diagnostic logs for details". I couldn't find any sign of any build logs. The app is still running the previous version and all the logs just seem to relate to that.

Now every time I try to go into the deployment center I just get "Fetching Deployment Data" with a loading animation but nothing ever displays, and the buttons are disabled.

As far as I can tell there is no way to raise this issue with Microsoft without paying for a support contract.

Is there anything else I can do to try and fix the problem other than (a) pay for a support contract (b) wait and hope or (c) delete the whole thing and try again?

***Update 19 aug 18:00 UTC:***

After leaving it for long enough it did occasionally refresh to show the status and build failure message. I updated the branch to point to a version which has definitely worked before and pushed it, and the exact same thing happened again, so it doesn't seem to be related to any source code changes.

So I deleted the whole web app in azure and re-created it. So far the deployment center is responding OK but I'm still getting `An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details` when trying to build.

In the LogFiles/kudu/deployment directory there is a text file containing a single line with the same message. In logFiles/kudu/trace there are loads of XML files (possibly one per click in the portal). one of them contains messages about building but there is no indication that an error has occurred.

The last line displayed in the build log in the portal is `Creating an optimized production build...` which is the react build step.

***Update 7 Sep 14:00 UTC:***
After waiting a few days and trying again several times, I gave up with kudu and, after several failed attempts, managed to build it locally and deploy it using visual studio.

It ran OK for several days but now it's gone to 503 unavailable. I can't retrieve the logs and trying to get onto the SSH console also just returns 503 unavailable. According to the status page it's running and according to the diagnostics there are no problems.

If I try to build locally and then deploy, the deployment appears to work but the site still returns 503. I even tried to set up kudu deployment again but that just fails immediately with a 503 error as well.

Several people have mentioned quotas when trying to diagnose this type - I have checked the quota page and all the quotas are 0% except file system storage which is 12%

Now I'm at a complete loss as to what I'm supposed to do. I could delete it and start all over again but I've done that recently so I see no reason to believe that's going to be anything other than a temporary solution.

Comment: Check whether you have enough space if not try deleting and recreating

Comment: if you mean disk space on the VM, yes there's loads of space

Answer (score 0):

The Free (and Shared) tier allocate resource quotas limit, which are reset.

Quotas for Free or Shared apps are CPU, memory, bandwidth and filesystem. You will have review all these resource quotas. As Sajeetharan pointed out storage is of the quota limit to examine.

To highlight more on this, the pricing tier of an App Service plan (ASP) determines what App Service features you get and how much you pay for the plan.  With Free and Shared (Shared compute) ASPs, these are two base tiers, runs an app on the same Azure VM as other App Service apps, including apps of other customers.

To review the status of the various quotas and metrics that affect an app, in the Azure Portal, navigate to the WebApp setting> App Service Plan >> Quotas option.  Kindly check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#monitoring-quotas-and-metrics-in-the-azure-portal) for more details.

You may also leverage App Service diagnostics from Azure Portal for pointers.
To access App Service diagnostics, navigate to your App Service app in the Azure portal.

In the left navigation, click on Diagnose and solve problems – Checkout the tile for “Diagnostic Tools” and “**Availability and Performance**”.

Comment: I've checked the quotas and I am at about 10% of disk quota and 0% for all the others